# How do I stop a related resource from appearing in a view in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've done some work following the django rest framework tutorial. I would like to add the ability to make a snippet private, so that no other users can see it. I created an extra field to the snippet and I have tried to implement this using object permissions. It works in that it stops other users from seeing it in the detail view (403 forbidden) and after overriding the list method in the ViewSet to filter it out, it is no longer listed there. However it is still listed under user as it is a related field.

How do I filter it from the user view so the API only returns resources the current user can see.

I have a models.py like so:

```py
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py:

```py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner', 'title', 'code',
                  'linenos', 'language', 'style', 'private')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, view_name='snippet-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

views.py:

```py
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.

    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        SeeSnippet, )

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Snippet.objects.filter(Q(owner=self.request.user) | Q(private=False))
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(queryset, many=True, 
                                       context={'request': self.request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True, renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

permissions.py:

```py
class SeeSnippet(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # If the object is private, then check if the user is the owner.
        # Reject if not as non-owners should not be able to see it.
        if obj.private:
            return obj.owner == request.user

        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DRF docs mention this limitation of their object-level permissions in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#limitations-of-object-level-permissions). Thus, the best way of handling this would be to edit the queryset in your list view to mimic the functionality in your permissions. Another option would be to use a framework like [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/check.html#get-objects-for-user), though it's pretty heavy-handed.

Comment: Thanks, I basically came to the same conclusion as you but I'll check out django-guardian!